# Android Supporting Multiple Screens

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi I created my own Android App. It worked well but when I tested it in multiple devices I noticed that it is not supporting Multiple Screens although my app call HTML files from assets directory  .

Activity XML

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    tools:context=".ElarabyGroup" />

 <LinearLayout 
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

     <WebView android:id="@+id/web_engine"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">
     </WebView>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Manifest

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".ElarabyGroup"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_elaraby_group" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: You can create different layouts for different dpi devices in separate layout folders.

Comment: the designer created the HTML files support multiple layouts but it isn't work well ,this mean that i must create separate layout

Comment: Can you show the display you are getting in different devices?

Comment: Because a webview is stretched to fullscreen if you have set it to match parent vertically and horizontally. I am not sure what issue you are facing to display the html